# How to reset variable in runnable in Android

Tags: android, handler, runnable

I have a handler and a runnable, Handler has a loop that runs from 0 to 5. when i start the runnable in handler it runs and increment value to 0 to 5. But if i double click or click more than 1 time than it takes the value of temp above 5. How can i reset (0) the value of temp on every click of handler.

```
    final Handler deneme = new Handler();
    final Runnable post_score = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            Log.i("TAG", Integer.toString(temp));
            temp++;
           }
    };


    Button tv = (Button )findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View arg0) {
               temp = 0;
               for(int i=0; i < 5;i++){
                   deneme.postDelayed(post_score, i *250);
               }
          }
    });
```

Comment: why you dont reset the temp to 0 in your click handler?

Comment: You can reset it before for() in the run definition itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way is to use removecallback